# assigning hover state to a data-id with css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to assign a hover state with css to a data-id. Does somebody knows how to do that?

I've tried to assign a hover state like this:

```
[data-id="23"] a:hover {background-color:#333 !important;}
```

that didn't work.
Also tried this:

```
[data-id="23"] {background-color:#ffaaa6; &:hover {background-color:#333 !important;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without spaces. In your first example you are targeting the hyperlink inside the data-id.

```css
[data-id="23"]:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="23">Test ID</div>
```